# Fedora 16 cancelled distro-sync, error duplicates on resume

Tags: duplicates, upgrade, fedora

I forgot one step in the 16 -> 17 instructions and now yum complains on distro-sync.

```
words-3.0-18.fc17.noarch is a duplicate with words-3.0-17.fc15.noarch
xemacs-filesystem-21.5.33-4.fc17.noarch is a duplicate with xemacs-filesystem-21.5.31-2.fc16.noarch
xkeyboard-config-2.5.1-4.fc17.noarch is a duplicate with xkeyboard-config-2.3-3.fc16.noarch
xsane-common-0.999-1.fc17.i686 is a duplicate with xsane-common-0.998-12.fc16.i686
yelp-xsl-3.4.2-1.fc17.noarch is a duplicate with yelp-xsl-3.2.1-1.fc16.noarch
zd1211-firmware-1.4-6.fc17.noarch is a duplicate with zd1211-firmware-1.4-5.fc15.noarch
```

aaaand so on. I tried complete transaction, but the same errors occur.

What do I do now?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved removing the old packages with
    yum remove
and reinstalling the already installed ones with
    yum reinstall